# Select a column from table based on other column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySql and table name is logs

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| domain        | varchar(50)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| sid           | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| email         | varchar(100)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The following are sample rows from the table

```
+------------+----------------+---------------
| sid        | email                 | domain|
+------------------------------------+-------+
| 1 |        | xxx123@yahoo.com      | xxx   |
| 2 |        | xxx123@yahoo.com      | xxx   |
| 2 |        | yyy123@yahoo.com      | yyy   |
| 2 |        | yyy123@yahoo.com      | yyy   |
| 3 |        | zzz123@yahoo.com      | zzz   |
| 4 |        | qqq123@yahoo.com      | qqq   |
| 2 |        | ppp123@yahoo.com      | ppp   |
+---+--------+-----------------------+-------+
```

I want a query something like

```
select * from logs
where sid IN (select sid from logs
              where domain="xxx" AND email="xxx123@yahoo.com")
```

Desired output

```
+------------+-----------------------+--------
| sid        | email                 | domain|
+------------------------------------+-------+
| 1 |        | xxx123@yahoo.com      | xxx   |
| 2 |        | xxx123@yahoo.com      | xxx   |
| 2 |        | yyy123@yahoo.com      | yyy   |
| 2 |        | yyy123@yahoo.com      | yyy   |
| 2 |        | ppp123@yahoo.com      | ppp   |
+---+--------+-----------------------+-------+
```

I can do it using joins but is there any way to get results without         using joins or any optimized version of this query

Comment: Are you looking for a simple SELECT statement or am I missing something? SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field1="value1" AND field2="value2"

Comment: Why do you want to avoid joins?

Comment: Your given query works well. Also, you have duplicates in your table.

Comment: Joins and  `WHERE IN` are equivalent and result in the same execution plans. Therefore, trying to avoid joins is pointless. If you have performance issues, it's because you are missing indexes or the query you used isn't properly written.

Answer (score 0):

First get a proper id on those rows. Second have you tried it? it looks like it should work. I have no idea why you want that though.

If it actually doesn't work try this structure, could be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE relevant_field IN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT relevant_field
        FROM some_table
        WHERE conditions
    ) AS subquery
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where exists` as

```
select l1.* from logs l1 
where exists( 
   select 1 from logs l2 
   where l1.sid = l2.sid 
   and l2.domain = 'xxx' 
   and l2.email = 'xxx123@yahoo.com'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want the whole table as result or just one column?

If I get your question right I would simple use:

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE domain="xxx" AND email="xxx123@yahoo.com"
```

Or if you want only the sid just replace the * with sid.
And if all sid´s are numbers, why don´t you use int or something similar as column type?

Comment: check sid, they aren't unique, there are two rows entirely duplicate even, the table is a mess :P

Comment: But although it could use a numerical type. Not as Primary key but just as values.

Comment: I didnt, but someone decided to downvote those that didnt notice why the sql has to be the way it is. OP wants to get all those with sid 1 and 2, but not because they are 1 and 2 but because those sids are linked to the combo of name=xxx and email=that email. Your queries dont work because there exists sid 1 and 2 that do not have that combo yet has to be returned only knowing that specific combo (eg 2, yyy123@yahoo.com, yyy has to be returned too).

Comment: Sry, that wasn´t against you.

And thanks, I got the question a little bit wrong, but now I understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are doing something redundant just by looking at your request you seem to look for

```
select * from logs where domain="xxx" AND email="xxx123@yahoo.com"
```

I dont't know why you are using the first part of the SQL string since this is not a join from other sql tables.

Or am i missing something?

Comment: If same sid exists several times, but only sometimes with xxx/xxx123@yahoo.com, all sid rows are expected to be returned?